# ViewModel not cleared on DialogFragment onDestroy

Tags: viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

Lifecycle v 2.3.1

Short Story: `ViewModel` is not cleared when `DialogFragment` `onDestroy` is called. That's it.

In my MainActivity, I instantiate and show a DialogFragment on button press:

```kotlin
private fun showConfirmDialog(message: String) {
    MyConfirmDialog.getInstance(message)
        .show(supportFragmentManager, MyConfirmDialog.TAG)
}
```

my dialog fragment:

```kotlin
class MyConfirmDialog: DialogFragment() {
    companion object {
        val TAG:String = MyConfirmDialog::class.java.simpleName
        const val ARGS_MESSAGE = "message"
    

        fun getInstance(message:String): MyConfirmDialog {
            val dialog = MyConfirmDialog()
            dialog.message = message
            val b = Bundle()
            b.putString(ARGS_MESSAGE, message)
            dialog.arguments = b
            return dialog
        }
    }

    private lateinit var message:String
    private val vm: MyConfirmDialogViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: MyConfirmDialogBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        message = requireArguments().getString(ARGS_MESSAGE, "")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = MyConfirmDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        with(binding) {
            btnDone.setOnClickListener {
                vm.doTheThing(message)
            }
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        /**
         * Observer immediately fires on second fresh instance of this dialog.
         * regardless of whether observed with this or viewLifecycleOwner. Thus before 
         * it can even be shown, this second unique dialog is immediately dismissed. 
         * The observer shouldn't receive an update until after btnDone is clicked.
         */
        vm.doTheThing.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.e(TAG, "observed doTheThing")
            dismiss()
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy")
        //VM NOT CLEARED
    }
}
```

I call `showConfirmDialog` a second time from my MainActivity, a second dialog is instantiated, but the VM is still happily sitting resident and NOT cleared, despite the first dialog confirming `onDestroy` having been called.

Thus is appears I can never use a `DialogFragment` with a `ViewModel`, if said dialog will be instantiated more than once.

This feels like a bug in Android lifecycle 2.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my own answer.  I was, in fact, instantiating the VM like this:

```kotlin
private val vm: MyConfirmDialogViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Had to change to:

```kotlin
private val vm: MyConfirmDialogViewModel by viewModels()
```

Apparently, the choice of delegate is absolutely critical.  Using the first delegate (`by activityViewModels()`) was automatically scoping the VM lifetime to the lifetime of the Activity instead of the Dialog. Thus even when the dialog was destroyed the VM was not cleared.

I thought scoping the VM's lifecycle was handled when registering the observer (e.g. `observe(this, {})` vs. `observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {})`), but apparently the choice of these two targets has only to do with whether you intend to override `onCreateDialog`.  To me, it's a confusing mess.

It would certainly be a better world if I didn't have to know absolutely everything about lifecycles and all their intricacies just to use the SDK properly.